# How to disable input fields per row if its checkbox is checked?

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, disabled-input

I couldn't find a solution to my particular problem, although there were a lot of topics about similar issues.

My code disables all the fields my table contains instead of disabling only a row per checked checkbox.

```
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="pageName[]"></td>
    <td>
      <select name="pageSelection[]">
        <option selected>-- Select --</option>
        <option>...</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="pageData[]">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="disableRow[]">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="pageName[]"></td>
    <td>
      <select name="pageSelection[]">
        <option selected>-- Select --</option>
        <option>...</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="pageData[]">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="disableRow[]">
    </td>
  </tr>
```

My jQuery code:

```
$("input:checkbox[name^='disableRow']").on("click", function(){
      $("table tr input:text, table tr select").prop("disabled", this.checked);
});
```

I unluckily tried to concatenate the code below:

```
.has("input:checkbox(:checked)")
```

Comment: because you select everything....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your code says that every input within the table should be disabled. You have to narrow it down to the parent.

Edit: Added a line which disables the checkboxes on default and switched from `click` to `change`.

```js
$("input:checkbox[name^='disableRow']").prop("checked", false);

$("input:checkbox[name^='disableRow']").on("change", function(){
      $(this).closest("tr").find("input:text, select").prop("disabled", this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
   <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="pageName[]"></td>
      <td>
        <select name="pageSelection[]">
          <option selected>-- Select --</option>
          <option>...</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="pageData[]">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="disableRow[]">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="pageName[]"></td>
      <td>
        <select name="pageSelection[]">
          <option selected>-- Select --</option>
          <option>...</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="pageData[]">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="disableRow[]">
      </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: It works. I've just noticed that after I check some checkboxes and refresh my browser, those checkboxes stay checked but the fields are not disabled. In other words, I need to add somehow one more event like `on("load click"...`

Comment: That did the trick. I just replaced `.attr` with `.prop` on the first row. By the way, I'm using `name^=` instead of `name!=` as it looks a little confusing to me though both methods do the job here. Your solution was much more shorter than the one I was thinking about. Thank you.

Comment: @Jurgen Thanks for the reply. I edited the code. No idea why i used `!=` instead of `^=`. It only works because the name `disableRow` is `!= disableRow[]`

Answer (score 2):

Try:

> ```
> $(":checkbox").on("change", function() {
>    var chx = $(this).is(':checked');
>    $(this).closest('tr').find('input:text, select').prop("disabled", chx);
> });
> ```

1. `change` event instead of `click`.
2. Store the state of the checkbox in a variable (i.e. checked/unchecked).
3. Use `.closest()` method to find the `tr` in which the checkbox is nested within.
4. From the `tr` use `.find()` to target the applicable elements.
5. Reference the variable in step 2 as the `.prop()` value.

### Demo

```js
$(":checkbox").on("change", function() {
  var chx = $(this).is(':checked');
  $(this).closest('tr').find('input:text, select').prop("disabled", chx);
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="pageName[]"></td>
    <td>
      <select name="pageSelection[]">
        <option selected>-- Select --</option>
        <option>...</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="pageData[]">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="disableRow[]">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="pageName[]"></td>
    <td>
      <select name="pageSelection[]">
        <option selected>-- Select --</option>
        <option>...</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="pageData[]">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="disableRow[]">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The code works fine. Thank you for step by step explanation too.

Comment: @Jurgen you're welcome. Please accept this answer if it resolved your issue by clicking the checkbox ✅

Comment: I clicked on "This answer is useful". I couldn't find any checkbox you mentioned. Maybe my device ain't showing it. I'll check for it later.